# Ruby object's initialization method never fires due to class method

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, initialization, class-method

I'm working with an RS232 pinpad and want to create a class for it that inherits from the [serialport gem](http://ruby-serialport.rubyforge.org/) so that I can use the methods the serialport gem exposes like each_byte while abstracting away some of the details when writing to the LCD of the pinpad.

The problem I have is that the serialport gem defines a class method named new which seems to preventing my `initialize` method from firing.

```
class SerialPort
   def SerialPort::new(port, *params)
      #some code here
   end
end
```

```
require 'serialport'
class Pinpad < SerialPort
   attr_reader :test
   def initialize
      @test = "success"
   end
end

kp = Keypad.new()
puts kp.x #should be "success", will be nil
```

I've tried defining my own class method named new `def Pinpad::new` which at least allows me to override the `SerialPort::new` method but it still doesn't cause the code in my `initialize` method to fire.

I'm new to Ruby so the solution is probably trivial but I'd really appreciate some help with this one.

Comment: Call `initialize` from `new`?

Comment: Are you sure that inheritance is the right approach? Wouldn't a Pinpad be a device that *has* a serial port rather than something that *is* a serial port?

Comment: @mu The pinpad is a device that is attached to a serial port. The reason that I'm using inheritance is that reading and writing to it can be done the same was as writing to a standard serial port however I'm wanting to abstract away the write method so I can call `pinpad.write_line(0, "some text")` instead of `serialport.write("\eS0some text.......")` but if you know of a better design pattern I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Composition. PINPad has a SerialPort as an instance variable and the PINPad instance mediates all access to its contained SerialPort, the outside world doesn't even know about the contained SerialPort, the outside world only sees the narrow interface the PINPad defines.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort I found how to implement composition in Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [forwardable](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module which does what I want

```
require 'serialport'
require 'forwardable'

Class Pinpad
   extend Forwardable
   def_delegator @sp, :each_byte, :each_byte

   def initialize
      @sp = SerialPort.new("/dev/ttyS0")
   end
end

pp = Pinpad.new() 
pp.each_byte { |byte| puts byte.chr }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to redefine self.new in your subclass:

```
def self.new(*args)
    super
    object = self.allocate
    object.send :initialize, *args
    object
end
```

Idea borrowed from: [Code Size and Dynamic Languages](http://ola-bini.blogspot.com/2007/12/code-size-and-dynamic-languages.html). This may not be the best solution, but on my end it appears to work. As mu is too short says above in his comment on your post, this does seem like it's a better occasion for composition rather than inheritance.